# Is there a way to save logs of the requests in httperf

Tags: logfile, httperf

I'm testing with httperf and i'm trying to monitor the single response time on requests. The result that is given at the end of the test doesn't work for me and it's too approximate. I was thinking about working on the single response times and analysing the distribution of these. Is there any built in function i am missing or a possible workaround?